# asp design display and rendered browser display are not same?

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

[image]

[image]

**MY PROBLEM is why it is showing different output[Hyperlink Named HOME] 
in browser( going above the div part ) 
when compared to design page in visual studio!!!
please Help me, i Don't know much about HTML, LEARNING.....**

***<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="project.login" %>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style>
    .back {
        background-color:chocolate;
        width:inherit;
        height:65px
    }
    .images{width:426px;
            height:65px;
    }
    .hyperlinks {position:relative;
                 float:right;
                 margin-top:-20px;
                 margin-left:10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="back">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="images" ImageUrl="~/images/images.jpg" />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" CssClass="hyperlinks">Home</asp:HyperLink >
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>***
```

Comment: Overall, Visual Studio is really more for "programming" - the designer it has for web pages, is geared toward it as well - hence, it shows you where your `controls` are (guides). You shouldn't rely on it for "pixel perfect" UI designing, particularly if you have complex css layouts. TLDR; do code in Visual Studio, then view in browser/s (IE, Edge, Chrome, FF, etc). Hth.

Comment: I'd just follow that up with if you're truly trying to learn HTML/CSS/JavaScript, then take the training wheels off and stop using the designer. The best way to learn is through immersion. Get in there and figure it out.

Comment: @EdSF and Chris If you guys can explain which exact flaw in the VS designer causes this difference, that would be wonderful.

Comment: @MrLister Details from [the source itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4c64s41.aspx) -  which IMHO, isn't a "flaw", more like focus (more on the programming side and leaves the "rendering" intricacies/differences to whatever client/browsers are out there)

Comment: @EdSF The problem is that Visual Studio's designer emulates IE in compatibility mode. I'll type that up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs only in Internet Explorer, and then only in compatibility mode. So apparently, the designer in Visual Studio emulates IE's compatibility mode.

If you boil the issue down to the minimum required to show it, you get this

```css
.back {
  background-color: chocolate;
  height: 65px;
}

.images {
  height: 100%;
}

.hyperlinks {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <img id="Image1" class="images" src="http://lorempixel.com/195/65" />
  <a id="HyperLink1" class="hyperlinks">Home</a>
</div>
```

This puts the floating link in the top right corner of its parent in all standards compliant browsers. But switching IE to compatibility mode will put the link below the orange bar.
(If you then give the link a negative top margin, it moves up a bit, but that doesn't change the issue.)

Now a makeshift solution is to use CSS that is handled the same by all browsers, compatibility mode or not. Something like this, for instance.

```css
.back {
  background-color: chocolate;
  height: 65px;
  text-align: right;
}

.images {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.hyperlinks {
  line-height: 110px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <img id="Image1" class="images" src="http://lorempixel.com/195/65" />
  <a id="HyperLink1" class="hyperlinks">Home</a>
</div>
```

A more permanent solution would be to make sure that Visual Studio's designer would show things in standards compliance mode rather than compatibility mode. However, I haven't found a way yet to do that.

Comment: +1 That VS would be using IE engine is "expected", much like the `browser control` in WinForms, just couldn't find official documentation on it. Also, beyond HTML/CSS, once   controls are added (e.g. data controls), they are visible in design view (but not rendered in any browser). Admittedly, if there are settings to handle, I wouldn't know... I haven't used design view for quite some time...